# Data transfer between two database of installed app android

Tags: android

I have developed two apps if any data get changed in one app , another app should receive get updated eventhough second app is not active . This needs to be done offline. Means one app db gets altered another app should get updated without internet and without waking up the another app.

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved with Android Interface Definition Language (AIDL)  for interprocess communication 
For more information, look here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl

There are lot of examples on internet how to do it. Like [here](https://github.com/afollestad/aidl-example)

Answer (score 1):

Use a **Sticky Service**
to synchronize the data of both the database.

In that sticky service you can check for any updates in one app's database and if there are any changes in one app's database then update the other app's database too.

---

Another solution to this query might be that in the onUpdate method (Where you're changing one app's database) of one app's database you also update the other app's database. I haven't implemented this solution myself, but it might work and you won't need to use the sticky service anymore.